# ng2-datepicker - DatePicker import not found

Tags: angular, datepicker, ng2-datepicker

I'm trying to use the ng2-datepicker but after I installed it from npm I can't import the module.

**app.module.ts:**

```
import { DatePicker } from 'ng2-datepicker/ng2-datepicker';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
   declarations: [
   Appcomponent,
   DatePicker
   ],
```

The DatePicker doesn't exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues, the first is that you should import from `'ng2-datepicker';`

The second is that you ought to import `DatePickerModule` and not just `DatePicker`:

```
import { DatePickerModule } from 'ng2-datepicker';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
   declarations: [
   Appcomponent,
   DatePickerModule
   ],
```